# How to select with condition?

Tags: sql-server-2012

How do I select with conditioning?

I have a table named'Tb_Debt' and the columns have

```
 1. DebtID int,
 2. BillID int,
 3. Debt_Amount float,
 4. Pay int,
```

In colum Pay insert with 1 and 0 instead of Yes and No.

I need to Select to Display again. If Pay=1 I want to display 'Yes' else display 'No'.

```
How to Select or create a new function in sql server 2012 database?
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: use case function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT OrderID, Quantity,
CASE
    WHEN pay = 1 THEN "Yes"
    WHEN pay = 0 THEN "no"
    ELSE "None"
END, other columns...
FROM Tb_Debt;
```